# Handling stacked item pages - Mobile

Tags: usability, mobile, navigation

I've been currently redesigning a mobile app that handles online shopping. Stumbled onto a problem that might not be a problem, but it feels inefficient and I'm looking for maybe some different solutions.

The app starts off from the main screen where you have multiple items to view. After selecting one it brings up a product-detailed page, which consists of *name, price, description, add to cart*... and in the end gives you recommended items.

Here's where my problem lays. If someone clicks on the recommended item it overlays the previous product-detailed page with a new one. You can stack these pages basically in infinity from the current setup. Right now the app only offers you an "X" in navigation to close that page, but no full close to return to first item or to dashboard.

[image: current setup]

---

Would just giving an option of full close and "go back" be a valid fix, or does anyone else have better ideas on how to handle it?

[image: potential fix?]

Answer (score 1):

*– If someone clicks on the recommended item it overlays the previous product-detailed page with a new one. -*

This is exactly how it should work. There are many possible reasons why a buyer clicks on a recommended product, including seeing that recommendation is better than the product they are currently viewing.

- Putting a return button on the article itself is trying to condition
  the customer's purchase. Returning should be an action in the store,
  not on the item.
- A close button makes sense if the recommended product opens in a modal window.

Possible solutions:

- The application should have a general `back` button that jumps to the previous visited page.
- The recommended product may have a `Go to product` button, by clicking on it the buyer knows that he/she is abandoning the current item
- The recommended product can offer both possibilities: `quick view`
  that opens a summary of the details in a modal window and `Go to product`.
- The application can have a *visited product's history menu* to
  immediately access all the products seen